# No Text Alignment option in CiviMail WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: civimail, wysiwyg

We are using civi 4.7.29 on wordpress 4.9.1
Some of our Administrators are not going to know HTML when they are creating a new mailing.  I noticed there are not any text aligning options in CiviMail for Left Align, Center, Right Align. Shouldn't there be?  Am I forgetting to install something?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.
Go to Admisister > Customize and Data Screens > Display Preferences
Scroll down and click the Configure CKEditor Button
In the space for "Plugins" Find "Justify" and save it.  While you are at it, add "colorbutton" and "font"

Comment: Also unicolor for custom color pallet this was a helpful answer!